# Subspaces questions

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ W = \{(x,x,xy,y,y): x,y \in R\}$. Is W a subspace of $R^5$? Is W contained in a proper subspace? Does W contain a subspace?

No because $(-1,-1,-1,-1,-1)$ cannot be obtained. 
I think so but can't find one.
No beacuase it is not even a subspace.

Comment: "No beacuase it is not even a subspace." I think you're mistaken about what the problem is asking. It's not asking whether $W$ has a subspace (and you're right, it can't have one since it's not a (vector) space itself). However, there are subsets of $W$ which are subspaces of $\Bbb R^5$.

Comment: Like $(x,x,0,0,0)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first reasoning is correct, as $v =(1,1,1,1,1)\in W$, but $-v\not \in W $, so $W $ cannot be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^5$.

Clearly $W \subseteq \mathbb{R}^5$ which is a subspace of itself. Regarding whether  $W $ is contained in a proper subspace: Let $V$ be the set of all vectors  $(x,x,z,y,y) \in \mathbb{R}^5$ such that $x,y,z \in \mathbb {R}$. You can verify yourself that V is a subspace containing  $W$.

Finally, the subspace containing just the zero vector is a subset of $W $.

Comment: It is asking for a proper subspace though.

Comment: I edited my post.